# Scraping only the NEWEST blog post with rvest in R

Tags: r, apache-nifi, rvest

I'm using `rvest` to scrape the `.txt` files of a blog page, and I have a script that triggers every day, and scrapes the newest post. The base of that script is an `lapply` function that simply scrapes all of the posts, and I later sort out duplicates using `Apache NiFi`.

That's not an efficient way to sort duplicates, so I was wondering if there's a way to use the same script, and only scrape the newest posts?

The posts are labelled with numbers that count up, such as `BLOG001`, `BLOG002`, etc. I want to put a line of code that makes sure to scrape the newest posts (they may post several in any given day). How do I make sure that I only get `BlOG002`, and the next run only get `BLOG003`, and so on?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# URL set up
url <- "https://www.example-blog/posts.aspx"
page <- html_session(url, config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

# Picking elements
links <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") 

# Function 
out <- Map(function(ln) {

fun1 <- html_session(URLencode(
  paste0("https://www.example-blog", ln)),
  config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

writeBin(fun1$response$content)

return(fun1$response$content)

}, links)
```

Comment: If it is really an ID which is only increased by 1, you could write this ID to a file and then read it for the scraping process. However you should be aware of that the newest ID might be 2 or even more higher than the latest known ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of the links you want start with 'BLOG' as in your post, and you only want to download the one with the maximum number each time the code is run. You could try something like this to achieve that.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# URL set up
url <- "https://www.example-blog/posts.aspx"
page <- html_session(url, config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

# Picking elements
links <- page %>% 
  html_nodes("td") %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")

# Make sure only 'BLOG' links are checked
links <- links[substr(links, 1, 4) == 'BLOG']

# Get numeric value from link
blog.nums <- as.numeric(substr(links, 5, nchar(links)))

# Get the maximum link value
max.link <- links[which(blog.nums == max(blog.nums))]

fun1 <- html_session(URLencode(
  paste0("https://www.example-blog", max.link)),
  config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))

writeBin(fun1$response$content)
```

Comment: Thanks! On the `links[substr(links, 1, 4) == 'BLOG']` - what do the two numbers refer to? Documentation says they are the start/stop spots, but I'm confused as to how they correlate with the `BLOG` links. Appreciate your help

Comment: It's a check to make sure that each one of the links starts with "BLOG", in case there are other links mixed in for any reason.

Comment: Awesome - makes sense. Last question: the `5` in `blog.nums` means it's only looking at posts after the 5th one? Or other? Thanks again, I owe you a beer

Comment: It's obtaining the numbers from the BLOG links. Since the link format is "BLOG###" it is taking all of the text from the 5th character to the end of the string and converting it to a number.

Comment: And the concept clicks... Much appreciated